# Using date to append filename to database backups made by cron

Tags: unix, shell, date, cron

I want to maintain multiple dated backups via cron but I can't seem to figure out how to concatenate the file name in cron.

Currently I just use the following:

```
/bin/mv /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/today.sql /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/yesterday.sql

/usr/bin/mysqldump --add-drop-table -u dbname -pmypass dbname > /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/today.sql
```

What I tried was no good:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump/mysqldump --add-drop-table -u dbname -pmypass dbname > '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/' . date +%Y%m%d . dbname.sql
```

So how do I concantenate that string in cron?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump/mysqldump --add-drop-table -u dbname -pmypass dbname > "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/"`date +%Y%m%d`dbname.sql
```

Comment: I'm sorry, first post here, just fixed it.

Comment: Great. In my case however I had to escape % with backslash: 
`date +\%Y\%m\%d`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the $(...) syntax.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump/mysqldump --add-drop-table -u dbname -pmypass dbname >
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/$(date +%Y%m%d)dbname.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to define a variable like this:

```
 export MYDATE="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
```

and use it concatenated like this:

```
...> /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/"$MYDATE"dbname.sql
```

Comment: That is especially useful if you work with more than one file. I often make backups for multiple databases, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Put the date command in back-quotes and remove the spaces:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump/mysqldump --add-drop-table -u dbname -pmypass dbname > /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/dbBackups/`date +%Y%m%d`dbname.sql
```

In (at least) bash you can also use `$(some command)` syntax instead of back-quotes. Not sure if it will work for cron, but you might try if you prefer that style instead (one benefit of that style is that they can nest without problems).